Add borders to specific rows in Sharepoint Lists
Is it possible to mark specific rows in Sharepoint Lists individualy and manually?
I add rows into a list every day, counting the amount of the row quantity in the first column, like 1. 2. 3. Etc.
Next day I start over from 1.
Somehow I should separate the rows by days to see easier how many rows were added a day, and which was the last one.
In Excel, I just added a border line to the day's last row. How can I do something similar in Lists?
Thank you!
I just found rules and column settings instead of setting a row individualy.

Several ideas here:

You can use JSON formatting to highlight a row when the index number in your first column is equal to 1. Start with the Alternating Row sample from GitHub and change the condition to your number column = 1
you could group the view by the created date, which will also give you a count of the items in that group.


If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
